# Php Syntax | use variable in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, syntax

I have been stuck on this syntax issue for ever now and none of the information I found on anywhere seemed to work.

all I want to do is use a variable, I have about 20-30 files that need to connect to database, changing the credentials on all those pages every time would be such a pain, so im trying to link to a Variable.php file.

this is the code:

```
    require( "http://domainname/resources/Variable.php" );
$sql_details = array(
    "user" => $DBUsername,
    "pass" => $DBPassword,
    "db"   => $DBName,
    "host" => $DBHost
);
```

this is how the syntax was before I tried to add variable, which when ran gives me no errors like when I try to use variable

```
$sql_details = array(
     'user' => 'username',
    'pass' => 'password',
    'db'   => 'database',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);
```

Comment: Can you show content out of "Variable.php" ???
Where do you define your variables like $DBHost?

Comment: Use relative path when you are using any ```require or include``` function.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: the path of require will not be a fully qualified url instead it will be a relative or absolute path on the same server

Comment: @mi6crazyheart is correct  +1

Comment: You had better show us the contents of `Variable.php`

Comment: ALSO Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: errors are displayed, was telling me denied access for user "www-html" when thats not the user I put in my variable. but I set an absolute path instead of the url link to include php file and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest as below.

```
require( "Variable.php" ); // Use Absolute path here

$sql_details = array(
    "user" => $DBUsername,
    "pass" => $DBPassword,
    "db"   => $DBName,
    "host" => $DBHost
);
```

Here you can use global keyword to use another file variable e.g global $DBUsername

Answer (score 0):

I ended up listening to the commenters and used the absolute path "var/www/html/directory1/directory2/login.php" and everything works fine now.